# MySQL auto updating column when no values change

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have an auto updating column set up in my table called `date_updated` with the DML definition as

```
...
date_updated TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
...
```

However, whenever the values in my update query doesn't change, the timestamp is not updated.

To enforce the updation of the timestamp even when no values are changed, the doc mentions to update the auto-updated column manually - [doc link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> To update an auto-updated column even when other columns do not
> change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example,
> set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

If so, my update query will now also have the `date_updated` column set to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Now my question is whether this will trigger a double update of the `date_updated` column ? ie.

1. By the definition in the DDL (`ON UPDATE`)
2. And by manually updating the `date_updated` in the update query.

If so, is my approach correct to have both the above added or should I remove the `ON UPDATE` definition in the DML for that column

Answer (score 1):

> Will this trigger a double update of the date_updated column?

No. If you give the autoupdating timestamp column a value in your UPDATE statement,  that takes precedence over the autoupdate logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any documentation/reference to back this up, so that I can accept this answer for others with the same question ?